# Change object name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to change the object name of a file stored on Google Cloud Storage from a Google App Engine java application?  I am using the Google Cloud Storage Client Library and I don't see an API for doing this.

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify the object, but you could use the [storage.objects.copy](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy) method. This will copy the object (in the cloud) to a new name. Once copied, you can delete the original object.

From Java, the copy operation would look something like this:

```
storage.objects().copy("bucket", "foo", "bucket", "newfoo", null).execute();
```

Then delete the original:

```
storage.objects().delete("bucket", "foo").execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an object name. The only option is to delete it and save it again with a new object name.

> Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot
>   change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime
>   is the time between successful object creation (upload) and successful
>   object deletion. In practice, this means that you cannot make
>   incremental changes to objects, such as append operations or truncate
>   operations. However, it is possible to overwrite objects that are
>   stored in Google Cloud Storage because an overwrite operation is in
>   effect a delete object operation followed immediately by an upload
>   object operation. So a single overwrite operation simply marks the end
>   of one immutable object's lifetime and the beginning of a new
>   immutable object's lifetime.

Comment: This is not entirely true, you can do a copy-in-the-cloud.